# Web App Access SQL using Managed Identity

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to connect my SQL Azure and my Web App using C# .net using Managed Identity. Its my first using Managed Identity and  I am just following this guide
"https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-connect-msi"

But I followed it and I cannot make it work.I am getting a time out error. And hopefully someone here can answer some of my questions and problem in my code. Here are some of my questions

- In the guide it uses the "https://database.windows.net/" to get its token, should I changed it so it could get token in my Azure?
- In my code I keep getting the following error when trying to open a connection

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.)

Here is my quick test code

```
SqlDataReader reader = null;
myConnection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbConnection"].ConnectionString;
myConnection.AccessToken = (new AzureServiceTokenProvider()).GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/").Result;
SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE PersonID=1; ", myConnection);
myConnection.Open();
reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleResult);
while (reader.Read())
{
    Persons person = new Persons
    {
        PersonID = int.Parse(reader["PersonID"].ToString()),
        LastName = reader["LastName"].ToString()
    };
    resuwww = person.LastName;
}
return resuwww;
```

And my ConnectionString is this

```
<add name="MyDbConnection" connectionString="Server=tcp:SERVERNAME.database.windows.net,1433;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: do you have an active firewall in place at your SQL database? If so, add the IP addresses of your web app to it. There should be four IPs on your webapp

Comment: The way you get your token looks correct, that should work - if you have added the Managed Identity properly as a user to the SQL database

Comment: Is my connectionstring correct? Because some uses "Server=" and some uses "Data Source="

Comment: I used one like this: `Server=tcp:xxx.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=mydb;`

Comment: `Server` and `Data Source` are synonyms.  Both are fine.

Comment: This is not a SQL Database firewall issue.  The SQL Database firewall will give you a helpful message.  This looks like a network connectivity issue between your client and Azure SQL Database.  Is this code running in Azure?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Yes this error is when its already running in Azure

Comment: I already allowed the IP address of my web app to the fire of the sql and still the same

Comment: @Billy  Did you add the [possible outbound IP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-inbound-outbound-ips#find-outbound-ips) of web app service in the firewall of Azure sql?

Comment: Yup I already added the outbout IP in the firewall of Azure SQL. Still same problem

Comment: @Billy try to edit connection string with database `MyDbConnection='Server=tcp:<server_name>.database.windows.net,1433;Database=<db_name>;'`?

Comment: @NancyXiong I ask help from the Azure Admin to check the Vnet and configuration. Because the Web APp and SQL cannot see each other. They did some change now my error has changed as well "Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'"